# Error en la transacción. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.7.1 Relay access denied

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

He desarrollado una apliación web MVC .NET, en la que luego de hacer algunas funciones envía un correo electrónico. Tenemos un servidor de correos local administrado con ZIMBRA. El problema es que al intentar enviar un correo a un servidor externo, la aplicación me da una excepción:

"Error en la transacción. La respuesta del servidor fue: 5.7.1 : Relay access denied".

¿Hay algo que este obviando en mi configuración?

```
//parametriza el servidos STMP para enviar el correo
  SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("mail.midominio", 825);
  server.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("correo@midominio.com", "clavecorrreo");

//instancia objetos a utilizar
  MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage();
  mensaje.Subject = "Asunto";
  mensaje.To.Add("destinatariovalido@hotmail.com");
  mensaje.From = new MailAddress("sistemas@midominio.com", "Sistemas");
  mensaje.Body = "Estimado Destinatario:este es un mensaje de prueba";

//envia el correo
  server.Send(mensaje);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He cambiado la cuenta de instancia del servidor, utilizando la cuenta de administrador o root y he conseguido pasar la autenticación y se ha enviado el correo.

```
//parametriza el servidos STMP para enviar el correo
SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("mail.midominio", 825);
server.Credentials = new 
System.Net.NetworkCredential("administrador@midominio.com", "clavecorrreoadministrador");

//instancia objetos a utilizar
MailMessage mensaje = new MailMessage();
mensaje.Subject = "Asunto";
mensaje.To.Add("destinatariovalido@hotmail.com");
mensaje.From = new MailAddress("sistemas@midominio.com", "Sistemas");
mensaje.Body = "Estimado Destinatario:este es un mensaje de prueba";

//envia el correo
server.Send(mensaje);
```

Comment: ¡Excelente! recuerda aceptar esta respuesta el día de mañana, de tal manera que contribuyes a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza:

```
SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("mail.midominio", 825);
```

Por:

```
SmtpClient server = new SmtpClient("mail.midominio", 465);
```

Y antes de:

```
server.Send(mensaje);
```

Agrega:

```
server.EnableSsl = true;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, he hecho el reemplazo correspondiente pero me da el siguiente mensaje: "Se excedió el tiempo de espera de la operación."

Comment: vas a tener que revisar los logs del server para obtener mayor información :)

Comment: esta respuesta sirve pero, en mi caso, el problema es otro.